# Combodate/moment.js DD-MM-YYYY dropdown - style issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, combodate

I am using combodate and moment.js to have a dropdown `DD-MM-YYYY`. It's perfectly functional and inserts data into my tables but only shows as unstyled small dropdown boxes unlike the demo.

I have tried styling it in bootstrap and css but it changes nothing and only seems to create issues. I've tried on multiple browsers with the same result and no errors. I have tested my jQuery and its working fine. I am running this locally, My code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#date').combodate();
  });
});

<script src="./js/combodate.js"></script>
<script src="./js/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="btn btn-drowpdown" method="post" name="date" id="date" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD" data-template="D-MMM-YYYY" value="09-01-2013">
```

I am still new to coding especially javascript/jQuery and its probably something very small I've overlooked. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: which demo are you referring to? the only [demo](http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/#) I found, has plain select boxes

Comment: The first demo on this page. http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/

Comment: My boxes show up extremely small with square edges. no styling at all.

Comment: There are a few things that could be wrong here...your input has a type of btn and btn-drowpdown (misspelled). Are you sure you didn't mean to have those as classes? Also, the first demo on the linked page uses actual dropdowns (`select` elements). Might want to start there.

Comment: could you post your css, or what css framework you are using?

Comment: Also, that page is using bootstrap's css. Do you have bootstrap included in your page?

Comment: @wholevinski the demo says `This plugin replaces <input type="text"> with dropdown elements to pick day, month, year, hour, minutes and seconds.
You can submit form as usual because dropdowns don't have name attribute and not submitted.` so he's good with the input tag

Comment: btw, type btn is not a valid input type, nor is the method attribute a valid input attribute.

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni `type=btn` is not valid. That's all I was pointing out.

Comment: Apologies, it was type="text" originally. I was trying anything to affect the style in any way in either bootstrap or css. nothing changed at all. I've put my css through validators and tested it on other inputs/divs so I'm certain that's not the issue

Comment: The jQuery and boostrap plugins are in the head.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

Comment: Is that the only bootstrap CSS file you have? That's just for bootstrap-select, not all of bootstrap. Try this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: I have bootstrap itself locally. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">` I have a lot of other pages working perfectly with the same head so I'd imagin its probably nothing to do with bootstrap. The pack came with a JSON file. Was I supposed to link that in somehow?

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using? The docs page of the component uses an old version of bootstrao (2.2.2), if you use that version, you will have the same look and feel.

Comment: @vincenzoC I'm using 3.3.7. I tried deleting my link and putting a link to 2.2.2 but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got it working, but had to come up with a different approach.

I copied the sample code on JSFiddle from Combodate Github's page and altered it a bit.

```
<h3>Combodate</h3>
<div class="form-inline">
    <div style="margin: 50px;" class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="date" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-template="D MMM YYYY" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I added a `<div>` layer to accommodate `form-inline` and `input-group` style classes for this component, otherwise the three generated combos would be shown on separate lines.

```
$(function(){
    $('#date').combodate({
          value: new Date(),
          minYear: 2012,
          maxYear: moment().format('YYYY'),
          customClass: 'form-control'
    });    
});
```

And then I added `customClass` to Combodate's init properties to style all three combos accordingly.

I don't know what OP is expecting as result, then I tried to guess it.
Hope it helps.

The sample is published in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/flaviocysne/4g5p46zd/

Comment: This is exactly the result I was looking for. Thank you so much!!